# Drupal 7 Views : How to reuse one view for multiple fields OR how to let user select which field view displays?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

**My Task:** I have content type which have 100+ different mostly numeric fields (big questionnaire for NGO with yearly reports). For one field I can use Views module to let user select which reports include (for example one year) and display it as nice graph (using for example Views+Charts). I would have to define about 100+ nearly identical views, which differs only by what field data they use.

**My Question:** Is there any way how to reuse one view definition and just change data from which field id display?

**Solutions so far:** I found two not really good solutions:

- Create one view, export it (using Features or similar way) and then clone this export, rewrite  field it uses as source and than add. But this just speed up creating one view for each 100+ fields.
- Use module [Views Dynamic Fields](http://drupal.org/project/views_dynamic_fields) - it allows user to select which fields to display. But I would still have separate definition how to display for each field, so not much better than add one view for each 100+ fields.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing your own Views field display plugin! This is actually all documented within the Views module folder: views/docs/views.api.php. Depending on your fields I'm not sure how you would exactly connect the data to the view.

Another alternative would be to just use a PHP Code field, and figure out a way to programmatically display the data from the field you wanted. The downside to this is that you wont be able to use that field to sort/search on with any filters as far as I know.